# What are some unfamiliar and/or special tricks used to evaluate limits?

Tags: calculus, limits, big-list

***What are some neat tricks used to evaluate limits that might be otherwise a problem to deal with?*** I'm not asking for methods akin to L'Hopital's rule.. which is often used.

My question is geared towards garnering comparatively less known\ esoteric methods to evaluate limits.

---

One example is: [image]

Comment: The trick you mention is nothing more than application of algebra of limits and standard limits like $(1/x)\log(1 + x) \to 1$ as $x \to 0$. It is better to learn the rules of "algebra of limits" and the standard limits rather than memorizing 100 tricks for 100 different scenarios. I wonder which textbook first printed this trick of $\{f(x)\}^{g(x)}$ and wreaked "mayhem" with "tricks to evaluate limits".

Comment: No textbook. And yes, I know the algebra of limits. Since obviously I know very little in Math, I wanted others to possibly post more interesting tricks I'd have no idea about. Agreed... Example is quite pathetic. But I was short of time.. and didn't exactly have any tricks of my own to share... @ParamanandSingh

Comment: In my school days I did have a pathetic textbook which gave the trick you mention. I just wonder if it was the first textbook to print this or some other textbook was more pathetic than the one I had. On the other hand if your goal in this question is to know techniques for evaluation of limits then "algebra of limits/Squeeze theorem" is adequate for almost all limit problems and remaining few are handled via LHR and Taylor. Unfortunately many students claim they know "algebra of limits" but don't use it for most limit problems.

Comment: Agreed. Yes, it is there in the textbook; I didn't learn that from there though..
Some contest (Possibly Putnam/IMO etc) problems require some additional techniques and/or theorems... or at least that's what I had heard..

Believe me...many books are probably more pathetic than the one you owned.

Answer (score 1):

$$x \to 0  , \cos x \to 1 \\\cos^m(ax) \sim 1-\frac{m*(ax)^2}{2} $$ My proof for this: Based on combining Taylor expansion of $\cos x$ and this $x \to 0$, so, $(1+x)^m \sim 1+mx$. Example for that formula: $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\cos^3(5x)-\sqrt[3]{\cos(3x)}}{1-\sqrt{\cos x}}=\\\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(1-\frac{3*(5x)^2}{2})-(1-\frac{\frac{1}{3}*(3x)^2}{2})}{1-(1-\frac{\frac{1}{2}*(x)^2}{2})}$$

Comment: In the limit with $f(cosx)$  ,l'hopital is hard to use ...but it made that easy

Comment: Yes. Indeed. This deserves +1

Comment: How do you prove this? This is amazing..

Comment: @Kugelblitz: Standard Maclaurin expansions. (But I think this solution is a bit sloppy as it is written now; one should always write out the error terms as well!)

Comment: this is another trick $$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(1+f(x))(1+g(x))(1+h(x))-1}{x}=\\\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(1+f(x)+g(x)+h(x))-1}{x}$$ just note that  $f(x),g(x),h(x),... \to 0$ like this example $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(1+x)(1+2x)(1+3x)...(1+10x)-1}{x}=\\ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(1+x+2x+3x+...+10x)-1}{x}=\\\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(1+55x)-1}{x}=55 $$ you can compare with hopital

Comment: @HansLundmark Thanks!

Comment: @Khosrotash That's cool as well! Thank you!

Comment: @Khosrotash: The problem with your trick is that it does not work in all cases. Let $f(x) = x^{1/3}, g(x) = -f(x) = -x^{1/3}$ so that $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(1 + f(x) + g(x)) - 1}{x} = 0, \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(1 + f(x))(1 + g(x)) - 1}{x} = \pm\infty$$ Its no use learning bag of tricks and better to stick to fundamental limit theorems.

Answer (score 0):

hint: $$f(x)=e^{\ln f(x)}\\ \lim_{x \to a}f(x)^{g(x)}=e^{\lim_{x \to a}\ln(f(x)){g(x)}}$$ now 
  not that $f(x) \to 1 \\\ln f(x) \to 0\\$
  $$x \to 0 \to \ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-...\\ $$ substitute x by $f(x)-1$ because  $f(x) \to 1$  so $f(x)-1 \to 1-1=0$
that mean 
  $$\ln(f(x))=\ln({\color{Red}{(f(x)-1)}}+1)={\color{Red}{(f(x)-1)}}-\frac{{\color{Red}{(f(x)-1)}}^2}{2}+\frac{{\color{Red}{(f(x)-1)}}^3}{3}-...\sim {\color{Red}{(f(x)-1)}} $$ now look above ,and put for $\ln(f(x))$

$$ \to \lim_{x \to a}f(x)^{g(x)}=\\e^{\lim_{x \to a}\ln(f(x)){g(x)}}\\=e^{\lim_{x \to a}{\color{Red}{(f(x)-1)}}{g(x)}} $$

Comment: I believe you haven't understood the question...

Comment: Do you looking for example to this formula  ?

Comment: Are you looking for tricky formulas (like that  ) ?

Comment: Yes. I'm looking for more tricky formulae.